# What is the minimum liquidity requirement for tokens to be traded on CoW Swap?

Tags: cow-protocol

When trying to trade tokens on CoW Swap (on both Gnosis Chain and Mainnet) some tokens are not allowed to be traded and show "Insufficient liquidity" message.
What are the liquidity requirements for tokens to be enabled for trading?

Answer (score 0):

CoW Protocol is allowing users to place orders without spending gas, instead the fee is charged from the sell token.
So CoW Protocol needs some minimum on-chain liquidity to determine the prices of the tokens involved in the order, which then allows to estimate the amount of tokens to be charged as a fee for executing the user order.

The liquidity requirements for a pair to be tradable on CoW Swap are as follows:

- Both buy and sell tokens must have sufficient onchain liquidity to estimate their prices in the chain's native token.
- **On Ethereum Mainnet:** The pools should have sufficient liquidity to allow buying 1 ETH with the token in question. You can try buying 1 ETH from the AMMs interface although CoW Swap does support also multi hop routes for this test. Supported AMM pools: UniswapV2, UniswapV3, SushiSwap, Swapr, BalancerV2. Additional pools are supported by independent price estimators. 0x is an example for independent price estimator that is being used. The list of supported 0x AMM liquidity can be found [here](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/sources).
- **On Gnosis Chain:** The pool should have sufficient liquidity to allow buying 100 xDAI from it. Supported AMM pools: Honeyswap, SushiSwap, Baoswap, Swapr.

Information is updated as of June 2023.